# Flutter Dart - Firestore doc with nested maps to data class with freezed

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

In Firestore my documents are structured like this:

[image]

In this example the map `lineup` has two children of type `map`. There might be more and there might be zero for other docs.

I'm trying to convert the `lineup` map of a DocumentSnapshot into a LineUp object generated by [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).

This is my code so far:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'line_up.freezed.dart';
part 'line_up.g.dart';

@freezed
abstract class LineUp with _$LineUp {
  const factory LineUp({
    required Map<String, dynamic> artistMap,
  }) = _LineUp;

  factory LineUp.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> parsed = documentSnapshot.data()?["lineup"];
    print(parsed.toString()); //prints { p88U4b5lbAwouMVjjNZX: {trackId: 53, name: Name2}, fbei2rdwqBuMDTuFwY4m: {trackId: 23, name: Name1}}
    return LineUp.fromJson(parsed); //Exception thrown: 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
  }
  factory LineUp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LineUpFromJson(json);
}
```

Obviously something is missing since nowhere `name` and `trackId` is defined in the freezed class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure about freezed, but you can do it manually so you get the hang of what freeze or any third party plugin is doing.

Create a class called lineup

```
Class LineUp {
String name;
String trackId;

factory LineUp.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return LineUp(
      name: map['name'],
      trackId: map['trackId'])}
    }
```

Then, somewhere along your code where you want to create the object from the document snapshot,

```
List<LineUp> lineupList=[];
for (var item in documentSnapshot.data()?["lineup"].values){
lineupList.add(LineUp.fromMap(item));
}

print(lineupList[0].name); // should print the name of your first lineup item.
```

Comment: So as you can see in my screenshot below `lineup` there is another map `location` in this document (the whole doc describes an event). Would you suggest creating a `Location` object just like you created the `List<LineUp>` object and pass them as parameters for an `Event` object? I was actually hoping for an elegant way to have it all done at once. But if that's the way to do it I'll accept your answer

Comment: Do the same thing for it and expirement working with maps, and see how it goes, it's more fun coding.

Comment: Your example is missing the code of the freezed object of the document containing your lineup, provide it and I'll give you the elegant solution you are looking for.